# Restrict vim auto completion to search current file only?

Tags: vim

`ctrl+n` and `ctrl+p` is very convenient completion for Vim, but sometimes it is very slow which may be caused that too many included header file in the current sources. Is there an option to restrict auto completion to search current source file (or opened streams) only?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to play around with the `complete` option.

From the help file,

```
The default is ".,w,b,u,t,i", which means to scan:
   1. the current buffer
   2. buffers in other windows
   3. other loaded buffers
   4. unloaded buffers
   5. tags
   6. included files
```

Personally, I have noted that removing included files was really helpful, so, in my .vimrc, I use:

```
set complete-=i
```

But you can remove (or add) other lists as well.

See `:help 'complete'` for more information.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a feeling for when this "sometimes" is (a large project, a complex C file with many includes, ...), you can also use the `<C-x><C-n>` local file completion, see `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N`. This way, you still have the default completion available and don't need to mess with the `'complete'` option.

Comment: Great and flexible solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`:help i_ctrl-n` says:

```
Find next match for words that start with the
keyword in front of the cursor, looking in places
specified with the 'complete' option. The found
keyword is inserted in front of the cursor.
```

The next step is rather obvious, isn't it?